# Yii : how to select 1 registration using the best method

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-cactiverecord

I have a table in the database and from this table i want to select 1 registration, using the UPDATE field, like:

```
select * from website order by update asc limit 1;
```

is there a better way to load the registration than using the createCommand ?

and once i load the registration, how to i update the update field ?

I would prefer using Active Records.

Comment: FYI: active record pattern is considered by many to be an anti-pattern, which causes extensive [technical debt](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html) and violates [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select one row from a database table using your model with CDbCriteria and CActiveRecord like so:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->order = '`update` ASC';
$model = Registration::model()->find($criteria);
```

Assuming that your model is called 'Registration'.

See the manuals for CDbCriteria's [order](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#order-detail) property and CActiveRecord's [find()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#find-detail) method.

You can then edit the record just as you can with any other active record and save as you normally would, i.e.

```
$model->update = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
$model->save();
```

(or whatever you want to set the 'update' field to be)

Comment: no problem glad to help! Have a look through the [Active Records](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar) section of the 'definitive guide', there's lots of good stuff in there.